# CASE WHEN, SELECT MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Guys I have something like this:

```
select  t1.milestone_id, sum(t2.value) / count(t2.value) as value2, value3
from    (
            SELECT  milestone_id, SUM(value) value , CASE WHEN (status !='done') THEN (value ='0') ELSE value END as value3
            FROM    project_has_tasks
            WHERE   project_id='52' and milestone_id !=0 
            GROUP BY milestone_id
        ) t1
join    (
            SELECT  milestone_id, SUM(value) value
            FROM    project_has_tasks
            WHERE   project_id='52' and milestone_id !=0 
            GROUP BY milestone_id
        ) t2
on      t1.milestone_id >= t2.milestone_id
group by t1.milestone_id
order by t1.milestone_id asc
```

Got this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NO3M2.jpg)

Can You please help me to get the value3 as values2 except 0
Such like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRly9.jpg)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your first line:

```
SELECT t1.milestone_id, sum(t2.value) / count(t2.value) as value2, IF(value3=0, sum(t2.value) / count(t2.value), value3) as value3
```

The IF statement works the following [(see the doc)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
IF(<expression>, <expression is true>, <expression is false>)
```

If expression is not NULL and not 0 it is considered true.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'value2' in 'field list'

Comment: forgot value2 is calculated

Comment: If I'll use:

SELECT t1.milestone_id, sum(t2.value) / count(t2.value) as value2, IF(value3=0, sum(t2.value) / count(t2.value), value3) as value3

then
value3 are the same as value2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestion. Below code is working good :)

```
select  t1.milestone_id, sum(t2.value) / count(t2.value) as value2, IF(value3 !='0', sum(t2.value) / count(t2.value), value3)as value3
    from    (
                SELECT  milestone_id, SUM(value) value , CASE WHEN (status !='done') THEN (value ='0') ELSE value END as value3
                FROM    project_has_tasks
                WHERE   project_id='52' and milestone_id !=0 
                GROUP BY milestone_id
            ) t1
    join    (
                SELECT  milestone_id, SUM(value) value
                FROM    project_has_tasks
                WHERE   project_id='52' and milestone_id !=0 
                GROUP BY milestone_id
            ) t2
    on      t1.milestone_id >= t2.milestone_id
    group by t1.milestone_id
    order by t1.milestone_id asc
```